# linkedin as a Federated identity provider of aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, linkedin-api

Anybody know when will aws allow linkedin as a Federated identity provider?
I am working on a app, it would be great if linked in is one of the options.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, kind of walk around.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-linkedin-auth0-social-idp/